# OpenCV Python, why Hough Circle Transform doesn't find all circles ?

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

I search for a long time what can be wrong but I don't really understand the impact of parameters and pre-processing
I cannot post image but on a very clear photo of euros , the program recognize some circles and not some other , even exaclty as clear as the others.

Here is my code :
 '$'

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np

 filename = r'C:\Users\roseline\Desktop\piecefacile.jpg'
 img = cv2.imread(filename)
 output = img.copy()
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #BGR donnant GRAY


 circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1, 70, 200, 100)  


 if circles is not None:
 circles = np.round(circles[0,:]).astype("int") #convertit en entier les données

for (x,y,r) in circles:
    cv2.circle(output, (x,y), r, (0,255,0), 4)
    cv2.rectangle(output, (x-2,y-2), (x+2,y+2), (0,128, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow("2015_TIPE_LE_DEM", np.hstack([img, output]))

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Sorry for the troubles, I wish someone could help me and share his knowledge I'm deprived of.

Comment: please post the image with your detected circles marked by contour lines. Or better, post your picture somewhere e.g picasa

Comment: It could be that you set the minimal distance too high. Additionally, you could lower the threshold. Did you set the minimum and maximum radii correct ? If your original image is noisy or e.g you obtained the data by microscopic analysis, I would try to improve the acquisition method. Furthermore, if you acquire a lot of images, make sure they look the same e.g similar brightness levels etc.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! The website didn't entitled me to upload image , but I made this link http://imageshack.com/a/img540/2425/Hy5rB3.jpg

Comment: what is the theshold ? I don't understand either what is the "dp" the third parameter . I don't know how to put them correctly because I don't know how to consider how many pixel a radius may be. How can I make all my photo hace the same brightness ? Thanks again.

Comment: Read some documentation, ask colleagues from the university. The matlab documentation is quite good (imfindcircles). Unless you do not post your images with the identified circles highlighted I cannot tell whats wrong.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img538/6857/BNemFA.png

Comment: I made this one to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you set the minimal and maximal radius of your coins wrong. The Algorithm does not detect the smaller ones because it does not look for them and it does find false positive hits because you set the treshold to low and the maximum radius too high.

Look at [this Tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) and [the documentation](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) and play with the parameters min_radius and max_radius (make both smaller). You could measure the radius of the coins (in pixel) in beforehand.

If you still get positive hits, play with the parameters param1 and param2. If you would like to automatise that, use cross correlation.

It would be interesting to see your grayscale image. If your real world data is as simple as the coin image you are really lucky. In many times the hardest part is to get rid of the noise.